# Laravel and Eloquent : Update multiple Model & Relationships

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

How can you update multiple models and their relations at the same time?

**For example:**

`EditPost` is a model with a `editor()` relation `belongsTo` `User` model.

Now lets say I have to update the editor in all the `EditPost` objects with `original_post_id`

```
EditPost::where('original_post_id',4)->get()
```

**Possible Solutions**

a. To do it by referring the user by ID instead of by the Model User

```
EditPost::where('original_post_id',4)->update(array('editor_id',3));
```

b. To do it by a `foreach` and saving each model

**However**

Neither of these appeals to me as they don't gel in general with the object concept of Eloquent or they would mean doing multiple updates instead of one.
I was wondering if Eloquent itself had a more elegant solution

Comment: I am sorry but I don't really get your question, what do you mean by hardcoding the ID? you are looking for an update between models, is not the above working for you?

Comment: Sorry. I meant using the id instead of the object in the update. This is working. I was just curious as to whether there was a more "Eloquent" way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify the other end of the association, but I assume you are looking for something like this?:

```
$user = User::find(3)
EditPost::where('original_post_id', 4)->editor()->associate($user)->save();
```

Comment: Thanks. How would this work if I have multiple columns to update though? If I run separate statements will they run as separate queries? If so is there one statement that can update multiple columns of multiple posts?

Comment: The provided schema has belongsTo for the EditPost, which means you are using a one to many relation, one to many is different in terms to many to many (if you mean this kind of relation).
If you are referring to updating multiple single posts for multiple users, then a loop would be needed, loop through the users and associate them to the necessary posts.

Comment: No, I didn't mean that I meant multiple columns. Say for example I have to update the `user_id` & the `post_approval_rating` in one update statement how would I do so? (in eloquent)

Comment: I believe (not tested) that this should work:
`EditPost::where('original_post_id', 4)->update(array('post_approval_rating'=>$some_value))->editor()->associate($user)->save();`